# Reading from .txt file and using .startsWith

Tags: java

I am having issues with storing data read from a .txt file, I am trying to store the data depending on what key is at the start of the line. but for some reason it is just printing out the document as it is.

Here is the code:

```
File file = new File(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());


            }

        if (connectionTab.startsWith("Connection: ")) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!sca.hasNext()) {
            break;
        }

        String connection = sca.next();


        if (!sca.hasNext()) {
            continue;
        }
        String otherConnection = sca.next();

        if (!sca.hasNextDouble()) {
            continue;
        }
        double distance = sca.nextDouble();


        TrainNetwork.newStation.addConnection(connection, otherConnection, distance);
        System.out.println(connection + " " + otherConnection + " " + distance);

    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

Comment: Start with reading *lines* at a time from your file with `nextLine()` instead of just the space-delimited `next()/hasNext()` methods

Comment: First thing is you're testing for `if (stationTab.startsWith("Station: "))`, but the Scanner uses spaces as the _delimiter_ and the space is _not included_ in the scanned text, so this `if` will always fail.  You probably want to test for `"Station:"` _without_ the trailing space.

Comment: Second this is — in the second half of your code where you are dealing with "otherConnection" and "distance", you start off that section with `try (Scanner sca = new Scanner(file)) {` ... this creates a _new_ Scanner that starts all over reading from the _start_ of the same file you just read from in the first section of code.

Answer (score 1):

You `continue;` the loop immediately with a **second** `if(stationTab.startsWith("Station: "))  {`. Remove that,

```
if (stationTab.startsWith("Station: ")) { 
    // if(stationTab.startsWith("Station: "))  {
    //     continue;
    // }
    if (!sc.hasNext()) {
        break;
    }
```